# Wrap div around image

Tags: css

I have a div around an image like this:

```
<div class="q">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" />
</div>
```

The result is that the div is bigger than the image. I would like to wrap it around the image giving it the same height and width (without setting dimension)

```
img {
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
}

.q {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
}
```

I tried height and width 'auto' but it also doesn't work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/1/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add these:

```
img {
    display: block;
}

.q {
    float: left;
}
```

and remove:

```
.q {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

I found this method the easiest,

```
<div style="display:inline-block">

            <p style="float: left; padding-left: 20px">
                <img src="Images/user.png" style="height: 200px; width: 207px" />
            </p>
            <h4 style="text-align: center">Client Zone</h4>
            <p>So, he played with that child, the whole day long, and they were very merry.</p>
    </div>
```

This example has text in it but, even if you take the `<h4>` and last `<p>` tag the

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" >
```

The "display:inline-block;" ensures the whole image gets wraped within the `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin and padding of the div to zero:

```
div.q{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here yo go

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img {
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
}

.q {
    width:300px;    
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="q">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" />
</div>
<body>
</html>
```